# Fortran - Cannot IMPORT `c_char` from host scoping unit

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, fortran, gfortran

I have a program written in Fortran (fixed-format source) and I need to link it with a library written in C++. Both my program and the library are using MPI so I am using mpif90 compiler. I have a short interface `interface.inc` containing bindings to the library, so I could call its functions in my program.

The problem is, I can't compile my code, because of a strange error:

```
/projects/test/meric/include/meric.inc:11:22:

   IMPORT :: C_CHAR
                  1
Error: Cannot IMPORT ‘c_char’ from host scoping unit at (1) - does not exist.
/projects/test/meric/include/meric.inc:12:21:

   CHARACTER(KIND=C_CHAR), DIMENSION(*) :: reg_name
                 1
Error: Parameter ‘c_char’ at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
header.h:9:19:

   implicit none
               1
Error: IMPLICIT NONE statement at (1) cannot follow INTERFACE statement at (2)
x_solve.f:51:44:

   INTERFACE_START( x_slv , "x_solve" )
```

As we can see in the following snippets of my codes, `C_CHAR` type should be provided by using `ISO_C_BINDINGS` module:

#### program main:

```
       program BT
       USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
       include 'header.h'
#include "interface.inc"
```

#### interface.h:

```
  INTERFACE
  SUBROUTINE FuncA() BIND(c,NAME='FuncA')
  END SUBROUTINE FuncA
  SUBROUTINE FuncB(param_name) BIND(c,NAME='FuncB')
  IMPORT :: C_CHAR
  CHARACTER(KIND=C_CHAR), DIMENSION(*) :: param_name
  END SUBROUTINE FuncB
  END INTERFACE
```

#### header.h

```
c---------------------------------------------------------------------
c---------------------------------------------------------------------
c
c  header.h
c
c---------------------------------------------------------------------
c---------------------------------------------------------------------

      implicit none

c---------------------------------------------------------------------
c The following include file is generated automatically by the
c "setparams" utility. It defines 
c      problem_size:  maximum overall grid size
c      dt_default:    default time step for this problem size if no
c                     config file
c      niter_default: default number of iterations for this problem size
c---------------------------------------------------------------------

      include 'npbparams.h'

      integer           aa, bb, cc, BLOCK_SIZE
      parameter        (aa=1, bb=2, cc=3, BLOCK_SIZE=5)

      integer           npb_verbose
      double precision  elapsed_time
      logical           timeron
      common /global/   elapsed_time, npb_verbose, timeron

      double precision  tx1, tx2, tx3, ty1, ty2, ty3, tz1, tz2, tz3, 
     >                  dx1, dx2, dx3, dx4, dx5, dy1, dy2, dy3, dy4, 
     >                  dy5, dz1, dz2, dz3, dz4, dz5, dssp, dt, 
     >                  ce(5,13), dxmax, dymax, dzmax, xxcon1, xxcon2, 
     >                  xxcon3, xxcon4, xxcon5, dx1tx1, dx2tx1, dx3tx1,
     >                  dx4tx1, dx5tx1, yycon1, yycon2, yycon3, yycon4,
     >                  yycon5, dy1ty1, dy2ty1, dy3ty1, dy4ty1, dy5ty1,
     >                  zzcon1, zzcon2, zzcon3, zzcon4, zzcon5, dz1tz1, 
     >                  dz2tz1, dz3tz1, dz4tz1, dz5tz1, dnxm1, dnym1, 
     >                  dnzm1, c1c2, c1c5, c3c4, c1345, conz1, c1, c2, 
     >                  c3, c4, c5, c4dssp, c5dssp, dtdssp, dttx1,
     >                  dttx2, dtty1, dtty2, dttz1, dttz2, c2dttx1, 
     >                  c2dtty1, c2dttz1, comz1, comz4, comz5, comz6, 
     >                  c3c4tx3, c3c4ty3, c3c4tz3, c2iv, con43, con16

      common /constants/ tx1, tx2, tx3, ty1, ty2, ty3, tz1, tz2, tz3,
     >                  dx1, dx2, dx3, dx4, dx5, dy1, dy2, dy3, dy4, 
     >                  dy5, dz1, dz2, dz3, dz4, dz5, dssp, dt, 
     >                  ce, dxmax, dymax, dzmax, xxcon1, xxcon2, 
     >                  xxcon3, xxcon4, xxcon5, dx1tx1, dx2tx1, dx3tx1,
     >                  dx4tx1, dx5tx1, yycon1, yycon2, yycon3, yycon4,
     >                  yycon5, dy1ty1, dy2ty1, dy3ty1, dy4ty1, dy5ty1,
     >                  zzcon1, zzcon2, zzcon3, zzcon4, zzcon5, dz1tz1, 
     >                  dz2tz1, dz3tz1, dz4tz1, dz5tz1, dnxm1, dnym1, 
     >                  dnzm1, c1c2, c1c5, c3c4, c1345, conz1, c1, c2, 
     >                  c3, c4, c5, c4dssp, c5dssp, dtdssp, dttx1,
     >                  dttx2, dtty1, dtty2, dttz1, dttz2, c2dttx1, 
     >                  c2dtty1, c2dttz1, comz1, comz4, comz5, comz6, 
     >                  c3c4tx3, c3c4ty3, c3c4tz3, c2iv, con43, con16

      double precision cuf(0:problem_size),  q(0:problem_size),
     >                 ue(0:problem_size,5), buf(0:problem_size,5)
      common /work_1d/ cuf, q, ue, buf
!$OMP THREADPRIVATE(/work_1d/)

      integer   max_zones
      parameter (max_zones=x_zones*y_zones)
      integer   x_start(x_zones), x_end(x_zones), x_size(x_zones),
     >          y_start(y_zones), y_end(y_zones), y_size(y_zones),
     >          iz_west (max_zones), iz_east (max_zones),
     >          iz_south(max_zones), iz_north(max_zones)
      common /zones/ x_start, x_end, x_size, y_start, y_end, y_size,
     >               iz_west, iz_east, iz_south, iz_north

      dimension start1(max_zones), start5(max_zones),
     $          qstart_west (max_zones), qstart_east (max_zones),
     $          qstart_south(max_zones), qstart_north(max_zones)
      common /array_start/ start1, start5, qstart_west, qstart_east,
     $                     qstart_south, qstart_north, qoffset


c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
c   Timer constants
c-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      integer t_rhsx,t_rhsy,t_rhsz,t_xsolve,t_ysolve,t_zsolve,
     >        t_rdis1,t_rdis2,t_add,
     >        t_rhs,t_last,t_total
      parameter (t_total = 1)
      parameter (t_rhsx = 2)
      parameter (t_rhsy = 3)
      parameter (t_rhsz = 4)
      parameter (t_rhs = 5)
      parameter (t_xsolve = 6)
      parameter (t_ysolve = 7)
      parameter (t_zsolve = 8)
      parameter (t_rdis1 = 9)
      parameter (t_rdis2 = 10)
      parameter (t_add = 11)
      parameter (t_last = 11)
```

#### meric.inc

```
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING

  INTERFACE
  SUBROUTINE MERIC_Init() BIND(c,NAME='MERIC_Init')
  END SUBROUTINE MERIC_Init
  SUBROUTINE MERIC_Close() BIND(c,NAME='MERIC_Close')
  END SUBROUTINE MERIC_Close
  SUBROUTINE MERIC_IgnoreStart() BIND(c,NAME='MERIC_IgnoreStart')
  END SUBROUTINE MERIC_IgnoreStart
  SUBROUTINE MERIC_IgnoreStop() BIND(c,NAME='MERIC_IgnoreStop')
  END SUBROUTINE MERIC_IgnoreStop
  SUBROUTINE MERIC_MeasureStart(reg_name) BIND(c,NAME='MERIC_MeasureStart')
  IMPORT :: C_CHAR
  CHARACTER(KIND=C_CHAR), DIMENSION(*) :: reg_name
  END SUBROUTINE MERIC_MeasureStart
  SUBROUTINE MERIC_MeasureStop() BIND(c,NAME='MERIC_MeasureStop')
  END SUBROUTINE MERIC_MeasureStop
  END INTERFACE
```

**Do you know, why `C_CHAR` is not being imported from `ISO_C_BINDINGS`?**

---

Then I've tried another way to compile the program:

#### program main:

```
       module tmp
#include "interface.inc"
       end module tmp

       program BT
c---------------------------------------------------------------------
       USE tmp
#include "header.h"
```

But now, the code returns following error:

```
header.h:9:19:

       implicit none
                   1
Error: IMPLICIT NONE statement at (1) cannot follow INTERFACE statement at (2)
```

The mentioned `implicit none` statement is in the beginning of `header.h`, but the interface itself is encapsulated in the module outside of the program.

**What causes the conflict?**

When I remove the `implicit none` statement from `header.h`, then the program compiles, but I'd like to understand, what's happening here.

---

#### EDIT

Source codes were added.

Comment: interface.inc or interface.h ? Do you run the preprocessor as you use # include and not the include statement from Fortran.

Comment: We are missing the code of `header.h`. Given the error is reported there it is rather unfortunate.

Comment: Rather than all this mess with header files, how about a short but complete single source that demonstrates the problem? I tried to construct one based on what you showed here and it compiled fine in Intel Fortran (I don't have gfortran here). I suspect that when you do that, you'll figure out the problem yourself. I also agree that there's no  benefit in using #include based on what you show here.

Comment: @VladimirF I'm sorry for the lack of clarity - I've added remaining source files.

Comment: @SteveLionel I'll try to do it, but I'm afraid it's not so easy - the software I'm trying to compile is pretty old and complex with many modules, so I'm not sure I'll be able to reconstruct this case.

Answer (score 0):

Amusing that the error happens in `meric.inc` and that file is not listed in the question. Also source of `interface.h` is shown but the files included are 'header.h`and`interface.inc`.

There are a couple of ways that `C_CHAR` could be hidden by the tie that error statement appears.

1. It could be in an interface body within an interface body. That outer interface body may not think it needs `C_CHAR` and so not import it, but then the inner interface body doesn't have it available for import.
2. If there is a `USE` statement somewhere in an include file that reads

   ```
   use ISO_C_BINDING, only: surprise_me => C_CHAR
   ```

Then this hides the name of `C_CHAR` even though the name would be accessible without the above statement in effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've added missing files into the question, so you can expand your answer if you want to.